# ajax response goes on loop if it includes window.print

Tags: javascript, ajax, printing, xmlhttprequest

I would like to print the screen when I get an ajax response. This is my code:

```
function print() {
        var request  = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request .open("GET", "printPage.html", true);
        var counter = 0;

        request.onload = function() {
            if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400){
                console.log("success");

                window.print();

            } else {
                // We reached our target server, but it returned an error

            }
        };

        request.onerror = function() {
          // There was a connection error of some sort
        };

        request.send();

      }
```

But I get an infinite loop on the response (I see "success" on the console multiple times), it's like windows.print() calls again the same ajax call. Whats is wrong with my code? How could I print the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that code is at global scope.

All globals (global functions, global vars) are actually properties of the global object, which we call `window` on browsers*. So by defining your function with the name `print`, you've overwritten the usual `window.print` function. So by calling `window.print` in your function, you're calling your function, not the usual `window.print`.

Just change the name of your function to something else.

---

*( * "Which we call `window` on browsers" Technically, `window` is a global variable, and so it's a property on the global object that, on browsers, it uses to refer to itself.)*